# How to find out if the user has moved from one page in Spotfire to another page?

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-analyst

I have a calculated value displayed on different pages in Spotfire. I want this value to be reset to zero, everytime a user moves from one page to another page.

I am not sure how to find out if the user has changed the page or not? Using Iron python, I can take Document.ActivePageReference and put this as a document property (ActivePage) and say that every time this document property is changed, it should trigger another script that resets that calculated value to zero. In this case, how to ensure that the first ironpython script is being executed to update property (ActivePage), whenever the user goes from one page to another? 
Secondly, is it possible to update a calculated value on a particular page using ironpython?

Answer (score 1):

To change page, just use scripts. Create a menu in a TextArea that you put on each of your pages. For each page you have, add a button/link with action the following script:

```
# Set X as a parameter of the script
Document.ActivePageReference = Document.Pages[X]
Document.Properties["YourPropertyName"] = 0
```

---

You can remove the navigation page with the following code, by adding it to your TextArea:

```
<style>
.linkContainer {
    display: none !important;
}
.pageTitle {
    display: none !important;
}
</style>
```

Then just set the navigation to `Step-by-step`. Note that this may be broken by future Spotfire updates.